# can't index rich documents on both solr 3.6 and solr 4.0 using update/extract getting "#500 lazy loading error"

Tags: solr, solrj

I'v just started to learn solr. From last 3 days I'm in trouble. I can not 
index rich documents on solr 3.6 and 4.0. I am using windows7 64bit.
what i tried is as:

First I installed solr 3.6 with tomcat-jetty.using BitNami Apache

1.tried **-Durl** command what i got :

```
error #500 lazy loading error
```

2.Download **curl** for my window machine and tried curl i got: error #500 lazy loading error

3.copied a program from solr tutorial to upload a file using solrJ for 
**SolrJ** in NetBeans IDE and tried a pdf files to indexed using 
update/extract
then i got:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Server at 
"myServer:port/solr" returned non ok status:500, message:Internal 
Server Error
```

4.changed solconfig.xml so removed **startup=lazy** from update/extract 
request handler and got the same thing

I re-installed solr 3.6 again but can't succeed. 4.0 gives the same error.
Same problem with some other request handler also like /browse says
etc.

Should i switch to Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the packager (Bitnami) did not include that library, even though they left Solr  configured to use that library. You may ask them to resolve it. Or you can deploy it yourself.

[Here's](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat) how to deploy Solr on Tomcat. Its equally easy to install on Windows; and it starts as a Windows service. Once installed, to enable the rich document support, copy the contents of `contrib/extraction/lib/` to a directory and point the `sharedLib` in `solr.xml` to that directory. If you have used that guide, you will understand those new terms :-)

Comment: thanx a lot @aitchnyu it seems that BitNami might not have configured that package, now i am using Solr 4 it (manually configured) it is working good.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you are satisfied with answers to your questions, kindly accept them by clicking the "check" next to it. Cheers!